# Composable not recomposing despite arguments passed into it changing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my code, a composable takes a list of Uri and then displays them turn by turn. However even if the list of Uri passed into the function changes, the UI doesn't update accordingly by displaying the image corresponding to the new list of Uri. However when I change the key of my Launched Effect from Unit to the list of Uri, the UI does update. Why is this the case? Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Composable
fun DisplayImageFromInternalStorage(imageUris: List<Uri>) {
    var currentIndex by remember{ mutableStateOf(0)}

    fun incrementIndex() {
        if(currentIndex + 1 < imageUris.size) {
            currentIndex++
        }
        else {
            currentIndex = 0
        }
    }
    if(imageUris.isNotEmpty()) {
        Image(
            painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = imageUris[currentIndex]),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
    //When I change the key to imageUris it does work
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while(true) {
            delay(3000)
            incrementIndex()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key parameter inside the LaunchedEffect block refers to how often that block would execute.
Passing Unit into the key only launches block for one time whereas passing in imagesUri as the key to LaunchedEffect block would execute the block whenever imagesUri changes.

And also you would wonder that the why composable does not recompose automatically as imageUris is a mutableState that you are passing from a higher function.
That's because you might have used the remember block while instantiating that mutableStateOf and the child composable is remembering the initial value.

To get the updated value of mutableState inside the child composable, you have to create another variable using the rememberUpdatedValue block.

```
@Composable
fun DisplayImageFromInternalStorage(imageUris: List<Uri>) {
    val currentList by rememberUpdatedState(imageUris)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting the imageUri list from a viewModel, and then collecting it using CollectAsState(). Shouldn't the uri list that I pass into the function automatically update and therefore trigger recomposition?

Comment: you're correct it does recompose when your list changes, but you can't see changes because you don't use imageUris list directly instead you just need the size of list. If you would have to use the list direcly for example displaying it using a lazy column, you wouldn't need the LaunchedEffect for that. But in your case you need to update a variable based on the size of imageUri list, so using a LaunchedEffect would be preferred in this case.

Comment: I understand that I'm only using the size of the list, however if the list changes shouldn't the list.size value change and therefore result in an updated UI. This doesn't happen till I change the key of the launched effect.

Comment: @AllenJMathew first of all the key in Launchedeffect block determines whether the launchedeffect should be executed or not after each recomposition so If you put Unit it means it will be executed just ones trought the whole lifecycle if you put True it will be executed on every recomposition and if you put a variable for exemple a list then it will be executed everytime the list changes. Second thing is you want your UI to change when ever the size of the list changes but you have to understand the only thing that can trigger recomposition is a mutableState and the list.size is Int .

Comment: Yes it makes sense now. So when I used unit as my key, the increment index function was only called once with the imageUri.size always remaining what it was when the function was initially called, because the function was only called once, at the first composition. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Changes**

1. `imageUris` as key for the `LaunchedEffect()`.
2. Simplified incrementIndex. (this can be a method if used in multiple places).

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun DisplayImageFromInternalStorage(imageUris: List<Uri>) {
    var currentIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    LaunchedEffect(imageUris) {
        while (true) {
            delay(3000)
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % imageUris.size
        }
    }

    if (imageUris.isNotEmpty()) {
        Image(
            painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                model = imageUris[currentIndex],
            ),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is a very clever way of iterating through each element in an array without going out of bounds. However, I'm still confused as to why I need to change the key of Launched Effect in order for the UI to update when the uri list changes. Shouldn't the UI regardless of the key?

Comment: @AllenJMathew Have you added logs to see when the data is changing?

Comment: Every time the uri List is changing, the function does recompose, however the Images displayed don't change.

Comment: That may be due to `rememberAsyncImagePainter`. I haven't tried this exact code. I am facing a different issue due to which I am unable to see the images.